# server 2008 sp2 hung not responding with kvm reset as well

Tags: windows-server-2008, not-responding

using server 2008 sp2 64bit os standard edition with all updates from ms site.
server was hung this morning, resetting kvm did nothing, plugging in another usb mouse on the back did not let the mouse light up red on it's optic end.

other machines on the kvm worked fine including the mouse.

server is rack mounted 4u supermicro systems or superserver.

had to hard power off and restart.

any thoughts? i burnt this system in well for a couple of weeks before deploying so it is kind of odd that this happened. any help is greatly appreciated, or if anyone can suggest software to install that can maybe send out the email when something like that goes down.

i looked for the minidump but nothing.
nothing in the event viewers either.
gd

Comment: found an event id 6008 and under the monitoring service for server 2008 the event happened at 11:11am nov 1 2009 and it is showing under misc failures with no real indication to the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe it's a hardware failure; did you test the RAM and the hard disk/s?